# How to call template for each dictionary elements?

Tags: xslt

This is my xml:

```
<A>
  <D>dd</D>
  <E>ee</E>
  <B>
    <C>1</C>
    <C>2</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

This was my xsl. I had to call template1 and template2 only few times for the same params:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">

     <xsl:template match="/A">
        <xsl:call-template name="items1">
           <xsl:with-param name="key">aa</xsl:with-param>
           <xsl:with-param name="value">bb</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
         <xsl:call-template name="items2">
           <xsl:with-param name="key">aa</xsl:with-param>
           <xsl:with-param name="value">bb</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
         ...
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template name="template1 ">
       <xsl:param name="key"/>
       <xsl:param name="value"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="/D"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
       ...
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="template2">
     <xsl:param name="key"/>
     <xsl:param name="value"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="/E"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
     ...
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now, I have to call my templates about 350 times for template1 and 350 times for template2, I have many key, value pairs.

I thought to make one dictionary with key value pairs and iterate over it on template1 and template2

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  version="2.0">

       <xsl:variable name="values">
            <item key="A" value="aa"/>
            <item key="B" value="bb"/>
            ...
        </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:template match="/A">

         <xsl:for-each select="$values">
           <xsl:call-template name="items1">
           <xsl:with-param name="key">aa</xsl:with-param>
           <xsl:with-param name="value">bb</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>    
         </xsl:for-each>

         <xsl:for-each select="$values">
           <xsl:call-template name="items2">
           <xsl:with-param name="key">aa</xsl:with-param>
           <xsl:with-param name="value">bb</xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>     
         </xsl:for-each>
         ...
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="template1 ">
       <xsl:param name="key"/>
       <xsl:param name="value"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="/D"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
       <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
       ...
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="template2">
     <xsl:param name="key"/>
     <xsl:param name="value"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="/E"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
     <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
     ...
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is that Is it good idea to solve my problem. How to get root node in templates, now current node is "item". I wanted to get value od D node at my template.

Comment: `It display @key and @value at foreach but doesn't call to template.` That's not clear. Please post a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @michael.hor257k One more question, How to change current node in template to root node?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. I suggested you provide code we can use to reproduce your problem. All you have given us are useless snippets taken out of context.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Now you know what I mean?

Comment: I am still guessing for the most part. Did you see the addition to my answer?

Comment: ok, thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without seeing the complete picture. Without it I can only guess you want to do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$prodDict/item">
    <xsl:call-template name="Item">
        <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="@key"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="param" select="@value"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that this requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.

---

### Added:

> How to get root node in templates, now current node is "item".

A convenient method is to place the root node in a global variable, so that it's accessible from anywhere. Here's a simplified example:

**XML**

```
<A>
  <D>dd</D>
  <E>ee</E>
  <B>
    <C>1</C>
    <C>2</C>
  </B>
</A>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="values">
    <item key="A" value="aa"/>
    <item key="B" value="bb"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="xml" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="$values/item">
            <xsl:call-template name="template1">
                <xsl:with-param name="param1" select="@key"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="param2" select="@value"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="template1 ">
    <xsl:param name="param1"/>
    <xsl:param name="param2"/>
    <item>
        <d>
            <xsl:value-of select="$xml/A/D"/>
        </d>
        <key>
            <xsl:value-of select="$param1"/>
        </key>
        <value>
            <xsl:value-of select="$param2"/>
        </value>
    </item> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
   <item>
      <d>dd</d>
      <key>A</key>
      <value>aa</value>
   </item>
   <item>
      <d>dd</d>
      <key>B</key>
      <value>bb</value>
   </item>
</result>
```